# Does anyone know what advapi stands for?

Tags: winapi

Usually I saw advapi32.dll loaded into the memory, does anyone know what advapi stands for?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It stands for **Advanced Windows 32 Base API** as it can be read on clicking with secondary (right) pointing device (mouse) button on file `%SystemRoot%\System32\advapi32.dll`, clicking with primary (left) pointing device (mouse) button on context menu item **Properties** and selecting next the tab **Details** with the **File description** showing this information.

Found on Microsoft documentation page [How RPC Works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc738291(v=ws.10)):

> Advapi32.dll is an advanced Windows 32 base API DLL file; it is an API services library that supports security and registry calls.

Answer (score 3):

**Advapi32.dll** is **Advanced Windows 32 Base API**.

This file is part of Microsoft Windows Operating System, usually located in the `%SYSTEM%` sub-folder, like `C:\Windows\System32` folder.

Advapi32.dll is a part of the advanced API services library. It provides access to advanced functionality that comes in addition to the kernel.

It is responsible for things like the Windows registry, restarting and shutting down the system, starting/stopping and creating Windows services, and managing user accounts.